# Process Builder: Convert text to a DateTime using formula

Tags: formula-field, process-builder

I am using a process builder to assign value to child from the parent object.

I have one relevant field on both,but having different data types so I am facing the issue. 
Parent Field data type: Text (skdate_finish__c)
Chid Field data type : Datetime (Invoice_Finish__c[image])

By using the formula I am trying to get the value : DATETIMEVALUE(skdate_finish__c)
This is not working for me.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: Can you provide sample of data in skdate_finish__c

Comment: I am not getting any error, but unable to get value. I am getting blank value in Invoice Finish. That means my logic is not working.

Comment: @Ratan : It's not working

Comment: @ karthikselva: sample of data in skdate_finish__c -->>> '26/8/2014 4:30 PM'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the format you are passing  in to the function.

> **DATETIMEVALUE**
>
> **Description**:  Returns a year, month, day and GMT time value.
>
> **Use**:  DATETIMEVALUE(expression)and replace expression with a date/time or text value, merge field, or expression.
>
> **Example**:
>
> - **Closed Date**
>
> `DATETIMEVALUE(ClosedDate)`displays a date field based on the value of
>   the Date/Time Closed field.
>
> - **Literal Date Value**
>
> `DATETIMEVALUE("2005-11-15 17:00:00")`returns November 15, 2005 5:00
>   PM GMT as a date and time value .
>
> **Tips:**
>
> - DATETIMEVALUE is always calculated using GMT time zone and can't be    changed.
> - **When entering a date as a literal value, surround the date with quotes and use the following format:** **YYYY-MM-DD, that is, a four-digit year, two-digit month, and two-digit day.**
> - If the expression does not match valid date ranges, such as the MM is    not between 01 and 12, the formula field displays #ERROR!

You would probably want to add more logic to your formula and pass the value in the format expected by DateTimeValue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can extract day, month, year, but how can I extract time from text.